# How can I retrive the geocode of the center of the map

Tags: center, mapbox

I'm using mapbox, I want to keep a pin in the center of the map, whenever the map moves, the pin would keep the position as still. The demo might be the effect of Lyft circle.

[lyft screen http://pasteio.com/m5fd6d1a0a78d9e905c828d0bb8a18154](http://pasteio.com/m5fd6d1a0a78d9e905c828d0bb8a18154)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found it, it is supper easy just using map.getCenter(); here is my code for sharing.

```
centerMarker = new Object();
centerMarker = L.marker(map.getCenter());
map.addLayer(centerMarker);
map.on('drag', function() { centerMarker.setLatLng(map.getCenter()); });
```

Comment: also, you can simplify things if, rather than removing `centerMarker` and re-adding, you just update it with [setLatLng()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setlatlng).  E.g. 
`map.on('drag', function() { centerMarker.setLatLng(map.getCenter()); });`